# rangeSlider.js no funciona en su version responsive

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema verán tengo una pagina web en donde implemente el plugin rangeslider en Pc funciona correctamente pero en móvil no me explico: cuando en móvil selecciono el slider no puedo hacer que suba o baje o cambien la cantidad que tiene,solo se modifica mientras se usa el scroll pero como sabrán con el scroll se desplaza el usuario en movil por ende no puede funcionar así
comprueben a lo que me refiero en la pagina

este es el link de la pagina:http://ucreativa.work/linux/nsite2/product.php

como podrán comprobar funciona bien en pc,pero si lo tratan usar en movil el slider  no funciona.

que creen que pueda ser?
anexo el código js que use no anexo el css porque es mucho código que no es relevante

mi pregunta es se puede hace funcionar este plugin en móvil??

https://rangeslider.js.org/ es el enlace del plugin que use

```js
var cpu_cur_val = '2';
var ram_cur_val = '4';
var disk_cur_val = '8';
var backup_cur_val = '30';
var ips_cur_val = '0';

function new_range (wrapper) {




    // Variables to use later
    var rangeWrapper = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__wrapper');
    var rangeInput = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__input');
    var rangeValues = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__values');
    var rangeValueNumberBottom = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__value__number--bottom');
    var rangeValueTextBottom = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__value__text--bottom');
    var rangeSliderPaths = document.querySelectorAll('.' + wrapper + '__slider__path');
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var mouseInitialY = 0;
    var mouseDy = 0;
    var mouseDyLimit = 25;
    var mouseDyFactor = 3;
    var max = parseInt(rangeInput.max);
    var rangeMin = parseInt(rangeInput.min);
    var rangeMax = parseInt(rangeInput.max);
    var rangeValue = parseInt(rangeInput.value);
    var rangeHeight = 320;
    var currentY = rangeHeight * rangeValue / max;
    var rangeMinY = rangeHeight * rangeMin / max;
    var rangeMaxY = rangeHeight * rangeMax / max;
    var scaleMax = 0.32;
    var scale, newPath, newY, newSliderY, lastMouseDy, rangeWrapperLeft, pageX, pageY;

    // Update slider value, initially using the `input` value
    updateValue();

    // Function to build the slider `path`, using the given `dy` and `ty` values
    function buildPath(dy, ty) {
        return 'M 0 ' + ty + ' q ' + mouseX + ' ' + dy + ' 120 0 l 0 320 l -120 0 Z';
    }

    // Function to update the slider value
    function updateValue() {


        // Clear animations if are still running
        anime.remove([rangeValues, rangeSliderPaths[0], rangeSliderPaths[1]]);

        // Calc the `input` value using the current `y`
        rangeValue = parseInt(currentY * max / rangeHeight);

        // Calc `scale` value for numbers
        scale = (rangeValue - rangeMin) / (rangeMax - rangeMin) * scaleMax;
        // Update `input` value
        rangeInput.value = rangeValue;
        // rangeSum.innerText = rangeValue;
        rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue;
        // Match the javascript value to real input value;
        rangeInput.setAttribute('value', rangeValue);

        switch (wrapper) {
          default:
            rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'cpu':
            cpu_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'ram':
            if (rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText == '0') {
              rangeValueTextBottom.innerText = 'זיכרון (MB)';
              rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = '500';
            } else {
              rangeValueTextBottom.innerText = 'זיכרון (GB)';
            }
            ram_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'disk':
            rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue + '0';
            disk_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'backup':
            if (rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText == '0') {
              rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = '0';
            } else {
              rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue + '0';
            }
            backup_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'ips':
            ips_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
        }

        // Some maths calc
        if (Math.abs(mouseDy) < mouseDyLimit) {
            lastMouseDy = mouseDy;
        } else {
            lastMouseDy = mouseDy < 0 ? -mouseDyLimit : mouseDyLimit;
        }

        // Calc the `newSliderY` value to build the slider `path`
        newSliderY = currentY + lastMouseDy / mouseDyFactor;
        if (newSliderY < rangeMinY || newSliderY > rangeMaxY) {
            newSliderY = newSliderY < rangeMinY ? rangeMinY : rangeMaxY;
        }

        // Build `path` string and update `path` elements
        newPath = buildPath(lastMouseDy, rangeHeight - newSliderY);
        rangeSliderPaths[0].setAttribute('d', newPath);
        rangeSliderPaths[1].setAttribute('d', newPath);
    }

    // Function to simulate the elastic behavior
    function elasticRelease() {
        // Morph the paths to the opposite direction, to simulate a strong elasticity
        anime({
            targets: rangeSliderPaths,
            d: buildPath(-lastMouseDy * 1.3, rangeHeight - (currentY - lastMouseDy / mouseDyFactor)),
            duration: 150,
            easing: 'linear',
            complete: function () {
                // Morph the paths to the normal state, using the `elasticOut` easing function (default)
                anime({
                    targets: rangeSliderPaths,
                    d: buildPath(0, rangeHeight - currentY),
                    duration: 4000,
                    elasticity: 880
                });
            }
        });

    }

    // Handle `mousedown` and `touchstart` events, saving data about mouse position
    function mouseDown(e) {
        mouseY = mouseInitialY = e.targetTouches ? e.targetTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
        rangeWrapperLeft = rangeWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    }

    // Handle `mousemove` and `touchmove` events, calculating values to morph the slider `path` and translate values properly
    function mouseMove(e) {
        if (mouseY) {
            pageX = e.targetTouches ? e.targetTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
            pageY = e.targetTouches ? e.targetTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
            mouseX = pageX - rangeWrapperLeft;
            mouseDy = (pageY - mouseInitialY) * mouseDyFactor;
            newY = currentY + mouseY - pageY;
            // alert(newY);
            if (newY >= rangeMinY && newY <= rangeMaxY) {
                currentY = newY;
                mouseY = pageY;
            } else {
                currentY = newY < rangeMinY ? rangeMinY : rangeMaxY;
            }
            // After doing maths, update the value
            updateValue();
        }
    }

    // Handle `mouseup`, `mouseleave` and `touchend` events
    function mouseUp() {
        // Trigger elastic animation in case `y` value has changed
        if (mouseDy) {
            elasticRelease();
        }
        // Reset values
        mouseY = mouseDy = 0;
    }

    // Events listeners
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', mouseDown);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('touchmove', mouseMove);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseUp);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('touchend', mouseUp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la clave es tener un *handle* con el estilo `touch-action: pan-x;`. Así es como está implementado en [rangeslider.js](https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js/blob/develop/src/rangeslider.scss#L94):

```css
#{$rangeslider--vertical} & {
    left: -10px;
    touch-action: pan-x;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
}
```

Este estilo restringe el desplazamiento a horizontal, pero como es un slider vertical el resultado es que el desplazamiento vertical queda deshabilitado. Como imaginarás, en los sliders horizontales rangeslider.js pone `touch-action: pan-y`. [Aquí](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/full/PXbPXL) hay más ejemplos de touch-action.

Como hiciste un slider personalizado con `<svg>` tendrás que ver cómo lo puedes implementar.

Fíjate en [el ejemplo oficial de vertical orientation support](https://codepen.io/andreruffert/full/meeOav).

Cuando se arrastra sobre la barra y no sobre el *handle* ocurre desplazamiento vertical:

[image: Arrastrar sobre la barra]

Cuando se arrastra sobre el *handle* y no sobre la barra no ocurre desplazamiento vertical:

[image: Arrastrar sobre el handle]

Como habrás visto, es común que los sliders de las interfaces gráficas nativas de los dispositivos móviles tengan un *handle* porque resulta natural que sea ese *handle* el que se arrastre. Imagino que deberías aprovechar esa costumbre para que tu interfaz gráfica sea más intuitiva.